# Jackson serialize a subset of a map

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a map which I want to serialize using Jackson but only want to serialize a subset of it.  Say I have a simple map as follows:

```
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key 1", "value 1");
map.put("key 2", "value 2");
map.put("_internal key 1", "value 3");
map.put("_internal key 2", "value 4");
```

Then when serializing this I want to filter out any item whose key starts with `_`, so that the serialized representation would be `{'key 1': 'value 1','key 2': 'value 2'}`.

I started looking at `@JsonFilter` but can't find any examples beyond very simplistic ones against basic types and nothing which appears to help with this more advanced type of filtering.

What's the best way to provide this custom serialization?

This is using Jackson 2.4, in case it matters.

Comment: Why don't you filter the map, and serialize the result? With Guava: `Map<String, String> filtered = Maps.filterKeys(map, s -> !s.startsWith("_"));`

Comment: Good question.  I'm not serializing the map directly, it is part of an object and it's that which I am serializing.  As such I don't have direct access to the map so can't filter if prior to serialization.

Comment: And can't you provide a getter returning the filtered map in the object that you're serializing (and annotate the full map with `@JsonIgnore`)?

Comment: delete invalid  keys from the map then serialize it.

Comment: Yeah I could do that but then I need to do it everywhere I use this type of map (which is quite a few places).  If I can use a custom serializer I only need to do this once.

Comment: @user3218114 The keys starting with _ aren't invalid, they're just not for public consumption so should not be serialized with the rest of the map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining a [Jackson filter](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter) which outputs the keys that don't start with an underscore, and enable this filter for all the Map classes via [the annotation introspector](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/AnnotationIntrospector). Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonMapSubset {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key 1", "value 1");
        map.put("key 2", "value 2");
        map.put("_internal key 1", "value 3");
        map.put("_internal key 2", "value 4");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        final String filterName = "exclude-starting-with-underscore";
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
            @Override
            public Object findFilterId(Annotated a) {
                if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getRawType())) {
                    return filterName;
                }
                return super.findFilterId(a);
            }
        });
        filters.addFilter(filterName, new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
            @Override
            protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
                return !writer.getName().startsWith("_");
            }
        });

        mapper.setFilters(filters);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"key 1":"value 1","key 2":"value 2"}
```