# Convert hashmap to json while filtering some keys?

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to convert hashmap to json while filtering some keys. I have tried with Jackson but the result always have all the keys in it.

```
Map<String, String> hashtable = new HashMap();
hashtable.put("KEY1", "VALUE1");
hashtable.put("KEY2", "VALUE2");
hashtable.put("KEY3", "VALUE3");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
FilterProvider filter = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("KEY1"));
objectMapper.setFilterProvider(filter);
System.err.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(hashtable));
```

My keys are dynamic, Is there more efficent way to do this?

Jackson method of filtering is perfect to me, since i need to generate multiple json's with different filter for the same HashMap. Is is possible to make this work with Jackson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391108/22253592) is the answer of your question. You should create mixinSource Class without any fields and add it to the objectMapper. Then you can filter out your map dynamically

```java
@JsonFilter("filter")
public class DynamicMixIn {

}
```

```java
Map<String, String> hashtable = new HashMap();
hashtable.put("KEY1", "VALUE1");
hashtable.put("KEY2", "VALUE2");
hashtable.put("KEY3", "VALUE3");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixIn(Object.class, DynamicMixIn.class);
FilterProvider filter = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("KEY1"));
objectMapper.setFilterProvider(filter);
String filtered = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(hashtable); // {"KEY2":"VALUE2","KEY3":"VALUE3"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a `FilterProvider` that includes a `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter`.

**Note:** In this example, the `validKeys` could be passed as an argument to `createFilterProvider` and stored on the `FilterProvider`, rather than on the `KeyFilter` driver.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.PropertyWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;

public class KeyFilter {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper;
    private static Set<String> validKeys;

    static {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setFilterProvider(createFilterProvider());

        validKeys = new HashSet<>();
        validKeys.add("KEY1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, String> hashtable = new HashMap<>();

        hashtable.put("KEY1", "VALUE1");
        hashtable.put("KEY2", "VALUE2");
        hashtable.put("KEY3", "VALUE3");

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(hashtable)); // {"KEY1":"VALUE1"}
    }

    // Derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232485/1762224
    private static FilterProvider createFilterProvider() {
        SimpleFilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider();
        final String filterName = "valid-key-filter";
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
            @Override
            public Object findFilterId(Annotated a) {
                if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getRawType())) {
                    return filterName;
                }
                return super.findFilterId(a);
            }
        });
        filterProvider.addFilter(filterName, new SimpleBeanPropertyFilter() {
            @Override
            protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
                return validKeys.contains(writer.getName());
            }
        });
        return filterProvider;
    }
}
```